# How to build a program inside Debian docker image on Travis-CI

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I'm new to Travis-CI and I'm trying to setup my repository, but it has to be built on Debian due to package dependencies.

However, Travis-CI doesn't provide a Debian build environment so I assume I need to use docker.

***How can I create a .travis.yml file that runs a command in a Debian docker image?***

**.travis.yml:**

```
sudo: required
language: generic

before_install:
- chmod u+x build.sh

script:
- ./build.sh
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian

WORKDIR /

USER root

COPY build.sh /

RUN chmod +x /build.sh

RUN /build.sh
```

Comment: The first thing for you is to build your Dockerfile and make your tests work locally. If you have done so already, please add it to the question.

Comment: I'm new to docker as well so I'll read up on how to build a Dockerfile and add it when I've finished.

Comment: @DannyB How do I access the files from inside the docker container?

Comment: It depends... but I guess what you are currently looking for is the `--volume` argument - that lets you mount folders in the containers directly to your host - so you can view them as any other file in your system.

Comment: @DannyB I have added my dockerfile.